# Windows Docker is routing to an unexpected IP and being lost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Look at this trace result:

```
>tracert -d 172.18.0.6

Tracing route to 172.18.0.6 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.2.1
  2     3 ms     3 ms     8 ms  10.11.7.113
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

You see on the second hop, it's trying to reach an IP that can not see the IP of the running docker image which is `172.18.0.6`. I don't know where it is configured.

You may see my docker desktop network config here: [image: Docker Desktop Network Config]

I already whitelisted all possible IPs in the firewall. Also, I have no problem running the images. The images see each other with no problem. But, they can't see the host either.

The Docker Gateway IP is 172.18.0.1 which is whitelisted in the firewall too.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [The Docker-private IP addresses are unreachable from Windows hosts](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible) or in a variety of other common situations; you probably shouldn't look them up at all.  How are you launching this container, and why are you trying to reach this IP address?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I am running the images via a docker-compose project. I try to reach the web server(Nginx). That IP is actually is the Nginx image IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone experiences the same problem, it looks like the problem came with upgrading to the new version of Docker Desktop which was 2.2.0.4.

Even uninstalling and reinstalling that version did not help.

So, I uninstalled the Docker Desktop and re-installed the older version 2.1.0.5. It started working again. There has to be some networking problem with the new versions.